# How to make resource available to the network?

Tags: 12.10, networking

I have this Building Simulator application that uses Django. It simulates different actions in a building and you can query it to see what is the temperature inside etc. I set it up on my Ubuntu Server 12.10 and it is located in my `/home/myusername/Documents/BuildingSimulator` directory. It listens on port 8000 so when I open: `127.0.0.1:8000/admin` locally, I can see admin panel. When I try to access it form my local network I can't. I think that is happening due to the fact that it is located in my `/home/myusername` directory which is available only to `myusername` user. Where should I put this application so that it can be accessed form anywhere? Or what should I do to make this folder accessible to anybody?

I should add that I have Webmin running on port 10000 and It works fine when I access it remotely.

Here is the output of `sudo netstat -tlnp`:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1530/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.39:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1252/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1252/named      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      966/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      749/cupsd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1500/postgres   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1252/named      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      784/smbd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13713/python    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1256/dovecot    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1256/dovecot    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1278/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      784/smbd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1256/dovecot    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1256/dovecot    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1806/apache2    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1766/perl       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1713/X          
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      2432/proftpd: (acce
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      1252/named      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      966/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      749/cupsd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      1252/named      
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      784/smbd        
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      1256/dovecot    
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      1256/dovecot    
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      1849/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      784/smbd        
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      1256/dovecot    
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      1256/dovecot    
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1849/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::6000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1713/X
```

Comment: Nothing to do with permission or directory location. If you can access it via a web browser the process listening on port 8000 can access the files. Please add to your question the output of `sudo netstat -tlnp`. What does happen when you try to access the website from another computer?

Comment: @EricCarvalho When I try to access from another computer Chrome says: `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 192.168.1.39:8000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port):

> django-admin.py runserver
>
> Starts a lightweight development Web server on the local machine. By
>   default, the server runs on port 8000 on the IP address 127.0.0.1. You
>   can pass in an IP address and port number explicitly.
>
> Note that the default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from
>   other machines on your network. To make your development server
>   viewable to other machines on the network, use its own IP address
>   (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0 or :: (with IPv6 enabled).

You have to run:

```
django-admin.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then you'll be able to connect from network.